# Is it possible to change from which "side" objects are added in the priority queue with the same priority?

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I am using std::priority_queue with some custom objects inside std::vector.
Now suppose I have objects with the same priority when I call top() function I get them in order from oldest to the newest.
So my question is it possible to change this behavior so top() would return the most recent object in the case of equal priority?

Comment: You could provide a custom "less" function that takes your own ordering into account.

Comment: Sure. Just give them different priorities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy (but finite) solution is to keep a counter, and use the counter's value at insertion as a secondary key for otherwise equal objects. Counting down instead of up will reverse the priority order.

Finite because the counter might wrap, but with `long long` that's not a big risk.

Comment: Could you provide an example showing how to do this?

Comment: @J.AntonioPerez: Just a `std::priority_queue<std::tuple<Foo, int>>` really. You get `std::tuple::operator<` for free.

Comment: @MSalters so I should create some internal data structure to keep track of objects with the same priority is it right?

Comment: @ArgusKos: You don't need a special type. `std::tuple<YourType, CounterType>` is enough. Tuples are lexicographically ordered by their fields.